# JavaFX - Rotate object using quaternion

Tags: java, javafx, rotation, shapes, quaternions

I have created a 3D skeleton out of spheres and cylinders [based on the Oracle h2O molecule example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/sampleapp3d.htm#CJAHFAF), and I want to rotate an Xform using quaternion values. However, JavaFX doesn't seem to support rotations using quaternions which is strange as I was under the impression that it was developed based on Java3D (which supports rotations using quaternions).

I have searched Stack Overflow and the only solution would be to convert the quaternions to a x,y,z 3 point rotation matrix as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145414/rotate-a-3d-object-on-3-axis-in-javafx-properly) but I'm not sure how to translate that mathematical formula into java code.

I'd appreciate any advice on how to use the quaternion values I have for rotation or any code on how to implement the formula provided in the link above, thanks!

Comment: The code for those expressions is linked in the post you mention, and a full project can be found [here](https://github.com/jperedadnr/Leap3DFX), and the class that uses it [here](https://github.com/jperedadnr/Leap3DFX/blob/master/src/com/jpl/leap3d/Leap3D.java).