# JavaFX get Euler angle from Transform

Tags: java, matrix, javafx, euler-angles, javafx-3d

I'm trying to make some sort of 3D editor, and I'm trying to make an "orbit" tool, much like the one in Blender.

[image]

Now I'd like to know what the angle is. I used the code provided by [José Pereda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956070/jos%C3%A9-pereda) that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817123/javafx-8-transform-to-pitch-yaw-and-roll-rotation-angles), but I need the angles to be in the range from 0 to 2π. I cannot retrieve them from the acquired angles since the output values don't range from -π to π and are different for every output.

Also, the extracted angles need to be relative to each other, much like if you put 3 different Rotate transformations where every following one is relative to the preceding ones, preferably in YXZ order, since that's the order I use everywhere else, as well as the model format the editor is going to export into.

As requested, I have uploaded [the part of the code that is relevant to the question](https://pastebin.com/kyrP055H) on Pastebin. As far as I could tell from the printed values, the angles are relative to each other in XYZ order. For angle calculation, I use the snippet from the linked question:

```
public static Vec3d getAngle(Node n) {
    Transform T = n.getLocalToSceneTransform();
    double roll = Math.atan2(-T.getMyx(), T.getMxx());
    double pitch = Math.atan2(-T.getMzy(), T.getMzz());
    double yaw = Math.atan2(T.getMzx(), Math.sqrt(T.getMzy() * T.getMzy() + T.getMzz() * T.getMzz()));
    return new Vec3d(roll, pitch, yaw);
}
```

Just a quick notice, I have very little knowledge of matrices and their transformations, since that's something we'll be taking in our school next year, which makes it harder for me to understand.

Comment: Quack! Quack! Quack!

Comment: Thank you, I don't know what I was thinking when writing the last sentence of the question.

Comment: Have you checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850937/javafx-how-to-apply-yaw-pitch-and-roll-deltas-not-euler-to-a-node-in-respec)? It applies a new rotation to the previous rotated state. If this doesn't apply to you, please clarify more what you are asking. A short code snippet will be helpful.

Comment: I have checked the answer and I use the method provided. I have already done the part where I rotate the tool relative to all the previous rotations/the local axis, but now I need to get the global rotation angles. I added more explanation and cleaned the unnecessary information in the original post.

Comment: Without a code snippet that allows us to reproduce what you are doing, what you get and what is not working for you, it is really hard to give you a proper answer.